# Get current rank using mysql

Tags: mysql, ranking

i've got this query to get the rank of rows, order by some field

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, id, ammopacks
  FROM users
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY ammopacks DESC;
```

How about getting the rank of "x" id, without ranking all them before? I don't want to know all users rank, just only one id.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
select count(*) as rank
from users u
where u.ammopacks >= (select ammopacks from users u2 where u2.id = x)
```

This doesn't do exactly the same thing.  This will do a real ranking, where users with the same value of `ammopacks` will have the same rank.  The original would give different users different sequential values in this case.

To get this effect, you can do:

```
select count(*) as rank
from users u
where u.ammopacks > (select ammopacks from users u2 where u2.id = x) or
      (u.ammopacks = (select ammopacks from users u2 where u2.id = x) and
       u.id <= x
      )
```

Comment: Using the 2nd query i'm getting the ammount of rows, not the place in the rank...

Comment: @Zuker . .. Here is the SQLFiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70ce1/7).  I modified the query to change the direction of comparison, because I noticed that your original query as `order by . . . desc`.