# Mysql rank based on column using FluentNhibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hql

I have following table

**Student [student_id,Student_name,Marks]**

I want to rank students based on marks and get specific rank position by student_id using FluentNHibernate

I wrote below hql query and got

> NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: A recognition error
>   occurred. exception.

```
NHibernate.IQuery q = session
  .CreateQuery("SELECT student_id, student_name, marks, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank"+ 
    " FROM Student p, ( SELECT @curRank := 0 ) q  " + 
    " where student_Id = '02610'  ORDER BY marks DESC")
  .SetMaxResults(1);
```

I think the problem is Hql cant recognize **':='**
please let me know if anyone knows how to solve this problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure about the content of the query (in MySQL).. hope you know how to do rank, if not check an example here:

**[Get current rank using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16451670/1679310)**

To use the proper (working MySQL) with NHibernate we have to adjust that like this:

```
NHibernate.ISQLQuery q = session
    .CreateSQLQuery("SELECT student_id, student_name...")
    .SetMaxResults(1)
    ;
```

The point is, the `CreateSQLQuery` returns ISQLQUery, which is in fact raw SQL, related to underlying DB engine dialect.

The previously used `CreateQuery` is about HQL, which is independent on the DB Engine dialect... but needs the Entity querying (not raw SQL)

Read more here:

#### [17.1. Using an ISQLQuery](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-creating)